# how to add wampserver in aptana studio 3

Tags: aptana

How to add wampserver in  aptana studio3. I did it in aptana studio 2.x but in studio 3, am not able to find that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no longer a servers view, but you can do pretty much the same thing with following the directions here: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Setting+up+an+external+web+server+to+preview+PHP+and+other+non-HTML+pages